# Bean returning null Values

Tags: java, javabeans

When I run the Test Runner class it should give the expected output as Views=1047 instead it returns views =0 i.e null value. What am I doing wrong?

This is my main class

```
public class TestRunner {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    JsonRestApi abc = new JsonRestApi();

    SocialBean bean = new SocialBean();

    System.out.println("Views="+bean.getViews());
}
```

}

This is RestApi class from where i am inject the values to bean

```
public class JsonRestApi {

public JsonRestApi() {

    try {

        String Response = "{\"Youtube Data\":\"Views\":\"1047\"}";

        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

        try {

            Object obj = parser.parse(Response);

            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
            JSONObject jsonObject3  = (JSONObject)jsonObject.get("Youtube Data");

            Long yviews = new Long((String)jsonObject3.get("Views"));

            SocialBean bean = new SocialBean();

            bean.setViews(yviews);

    }
  }
```

}
}

This is my bean class

```
public class SocialBean {
private long views;
public long getViews() {
        return views;
    }
    public void setViews(long views) {
        this.views = views;
    }
```

Comment: Why should `abc` have any effect upon the `bean` in your main method? It affects the one it creates in its own constructor, which then immediately goes out of scope.

Comment: You have two instances of `SocialBean`, one that you're creating in `TestRunner` and one in `JsonRestApi`. You're not using Spring at all in this code, and you're not doing any dependency injection. (You say you are "injecting values into the bean", but you're not injecting anything).

Comment: Is their any way i can access the bean value set inside the JsonRestApi contructor in Test Runner class?

Comment: The whole question has to do nothing with Spring. Are you sure you even got the idea of dependency injection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SocialBean is local to JsonRestApi constructor. Makes it as private field.

```
private SocialBean bean = new SocialBean();
public JsonRestApi() {

try {

    String Response = "{\"Youtube Data\":\"Views\":\"1047\"}";

    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

    try {

        Object obj = parser.parse(Response);

        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
        JSONObject jsonObject3  = (JSONObject)jsonObject.get("Youtube Data");

        Long yviews = new Long((String)jsonObject3.get("Views"));

        bean.setViews(yviews);

 }
}

public SocialBean getSocialBean(){
   return bean;
}
```

In your main method :

```
System.out.println("Views="+abc.getSocialBean().getViews());
```

FYI : you are not using Spring bean in this code.

Comment: still the views is returning null value

Comment: I think that your json is not valid.

Comment: String Response = "{\"Youtube Data\":{\"Views\":\"1047\"}}";